# How to downgrade Angular materia Version 16.0.0 to 14.2.6

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angular-cli, downgrade

How to downgrade Angular materia Version 16.0.0 to 14.2.6 so that colud be compatible with current project in term of appearance and animations

I tried to downgrade angular version but no Effect on its

```
ng --version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2
ng --version
```

Comment: You should change the version of @angular/material as well. You can change it manually at package.json as well.

Comment: The code you posted just downgrades the global installation of the Angular CLI, it has nothing to do with your project. To downgrade your Angular project, you should go to your `package.json` and downgrade all packages prefixed with `@angular/`. Additionally, you might need to downgrade other third party packages, like `typescript`.